# android bufferedwriter error

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an android app where I need to create a file and write/read on it using bufferedwrite and bufferedread. The file is declared in the activity as follows:

```
String string = "string";
File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), string);
```

When I try to write to the file using this code, however:

```
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(file)));
    out.write("I am a line of text written in" + file);
    out.close();
```

I keep getting a "constructer File(File) is undefined" error. I believe the error has to do with the file declaration, but I'm not sure why.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, `File` has no such constructor, so why are you surprised? Just use `file` directly

Comment: i don't know how i missed that, i guess it has to do with not using java for 3+ years. But then again this happens in not only java, so I guess i need some sleep. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String string = "string";
File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), string);

BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
out.write("I am a line of text written in" + file);
out.close();
```